# Open access form in upper left corner

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, forms-authentication

Here's my situation; I have a form (sub-form) inside another form which contains my navigation header

When the form is opened, access scrolls down to the second form (the upper left corner starts with the sub-form and to do this it goes down pass the form with the navigation header), call me a perfectionnist, but it's kinda annoying having to always scroll up when I want to navigate out of this form and into another. Is there anyway I can get access to open starting from the first form? Thanks!

Comment: Relaxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options you can do to have Access open a form when the application opens:

AutoExec Macro:
  - This is my preferred approach.  The AutoExec macro will run automatically when the application is opened.  From there, you can set a form open event within the macro or call a VBA script

Database Properties:
  -  A bit more out of the way, but under File > Options > Current Database > Display Form: You can assign the form you want the application to open.